# How can I figure out if a certain key exists in a mapping, Struct defined inside Library (in Solidity)?

Tags: solidity, mapping

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

library Library {
  struct data {
     unit val;
   }
}
```

---

```
contract Array{
    using Library for Library.data;
    mapping(address => Library.data) clusterContract;
    
    function addCluster(address id) returns(bool){
        if (clusterContract[id] == address(0)) {  // error occurs!
            clusterContract[id] = list;
            return true;
        }
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Following comparission `if (clusterContract[id] == address(0))` gives the following error:

```
Operator == not compatible with types struct Library.data storage ref and address
E               if(clusterContract[id] == address(0)) {...
```

How could I fix this error?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can't directly find out if any key exists in a mapping, ever, because they all exist.

```
mapping(key => value) name;
```

creates a namespace in which all possible keys exist, and values are initialized to 0/false.

If you want to check that a value was explicitly set, and not merely the default (0), then you have to program something. In some cases, `value > 0` is enough, but if 0 has meaning in your application, then another struct member can help ... `bool isValue;`, for example.

```
library Library {
  struct data {
     uint val;
     bool isValue;
   }
}

contract Array{
    
    using Library for Library.data;
    mapping(address => Library.data) clusterContract;

    function addCluster(address id) returns(bool){
        if(clusterContract[id].isValue) throw; // duplicate key
        // insert this 
        return true; 
    }
}
```

I noticed "`addCluster`" has the appearance of a contract factory (in progress), so you probably intend to keep track of contracts created as you go.

I assembled a little summary of different ways of organizing common data patterns in Solidity. It might be helpful to take a look here: [Blog: Simple Storage Patterns in Solidity](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/blog-simple-storage-patterns-in-solidity)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Under `// insert this` I have to put `clusterContract[id].isValue=true` so when same id is provided on the next function call, it will enter into `throw`; right? And thank you for the the design patterns I will work on them. @RobHitchens.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. You explicitly mark it in a way that leaves no doubt about the data being "real". I just figured you were planning to press on and create a contract and then you would need a way to store the address ... or similar.

Comment: Could you explain (or potentially point me to a resource) that explains this idea of `creates a namespace in which all possible keys exist, and values are initialized to 0/false`. What are the memory implications of this? Does it dynamically instantiate a struct when I try to access it?

Comment: I took a stab at explaining mappings here. https://medium.com/@robhitchens/solidity-crud-part-1-824ffa69509a

Answer (score 3):

This solution seems working, but I am open to any advices.

In `C` following should not work since `clusterContract[id].flag` does not exist in the first call to create map for `id`. But in this example `clusterContract[id].flag != 1` returns `true` at initial step to create map from `id`. After `clusterContract[id].flag`assigned to 1 `clusterContract[id].flag != 1` returns false.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

library Library {
  struct data {
     uint val;
     uint8 flag;
   }
}

contract Array{
    using Library for Library.data;
    mapping(address => Library.data) clusterContract;

    function addCluster(address id) returns(bool){
        if(clusterContract[id].flag != 1 ){ 
            clusterContract[id] = list;
            clusterContract[id].flag = 1;
            return true;
        }
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does exist and it defaults to false, so != 1/true. It doesn't need someone to set it in order to exist. In a mapping, all possible keys exist and corresponding values have zeroish defaults.

Comment: Are you trying to track structs for entities that have predetermined addresses, such as users who enroll, or are you trying to create new contracts on demand? Or maybe a little bit of both?

Comment: I am trying to do first one, like you said students who enroll. If the same user try to enroll again, contract should not allow since it has enrolled already. @RobHitchens