# Check if a mapped value for a struct exists

Tags: mapping, struct

I have the following in my contract:

```
struct familyMember {
        bool isParent;
        string name;
        uint balance;
        bool active;
        uint spendLimit;
        address accountNumber;
    }

    mapping (address => familyMember) familyMembers;
    address[] public familyMemberAccounts;
```

I have the following function I want to use to check if a mapping exists for a given struct:

```
function checkFamilyMember(address _address) private view returns (bool) {
        bool familyMemberExists = false;
        if (bytes(familyMembers[_address].name).length != 0) {
            familyMemberExists = true;
        }
        return familyMemberExists;
    }
```

I don't think this is working as intended but am not sure how I can debug. I would normally use a console.log() but I dont think I can do this in Remix.

Is this a correct way to check if mapped struct exists or is there a better way? I did not see any recent answers (I am using version 0.8.0). This [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13021/how-can-you-figure-out-if-a-certain-key-exists-in-a-mapping-struct-defined-insi) is 4 years old, so I wanted to know if there might be a new way.

Comment: Nothing has changed. If you want to known if a mapping entry exists you should add a field to the struct or reuse an existing field for such purpose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you figure out if a certain key exists in a mapping, Struct defined inside Library (in Solidity)?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13021/how-can-you-figure-out-if-a-certain-key-exists-in-a-mapping-struct-defined-insi)

Comment: Thanks @Ismael, yes, the link you mentioned was helpful. I had already reviewed it and mentioned it in my post. I modeled my code based on that answer as well.

I just wanted to see if there have been any new ways to handle this in the last 4 years since solidity is changing so much. Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest to not use a string field for such purpose, using a fixed size type like bool, uintNNN, bytesNN will work better.

Comment: Thanks, I will use a bool instead of a string.